# Android Realm, Data clears when application swiped out of memory

Tags: android, realm

I have implemented Realm in my Android application, when the application is installed for the first time, the data is stored perfectly.

When I log out i delete my user's stored data using Realm.deleteAll() method.
When I log in again, I get the fresh data from the server, which is stored in Realm. When the app is taken offline without getting it out of memory, the data persists. I have exported the Realm file and I have seen the data in Realm browser.

But when I swipe the application out of the memory, and again launch the application(in the offline mode), the Realm database has no data.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are most definitely calling `Realm.deleteAll()` somewhere, where you don't expect. Do a Ctrl+Shift+F in Android Studio and find it.

Comment: Ok I will try that for sure

Comment: I just dropped the db and created it again, it was a conflicting problem with my logout mechanism. Thank you for your help people.